# creating a formula field that takes value from another object

Tags: apex, lookup, formula-field

I have 2 objects: `Object A` and `District_Stats__c`. There are 4 useful fields in District_Stats__c: `District_Num__c`, `Month__c`, `Year__c`, `District_Rev__c`.

In `Object A`, I have `District_Num__c`, `Month__c` and `Year__c` along with other fields.

Is there a way to create a formula or a lookup field which would map the `District_Rev__c` from District table to `Object A`? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy creating a lookup from an `Object A` record to `District_Stats__c` then you can just use a formula along the lines of:

```
District_Stats__r.District_Rev__c
```

Where `Distrit_Stas__r` is the relationship name of the lookup field. Given that you have year month etc. on `Object A`it sounds like this solution would work.

If however, you didn't want a lookup for some reason you could create a corresponding field on `Object A` and populate that with a trigger before insert/update based the values of the other  fields.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can create a lookup field in the object A which looks up to the `District_stats__c` object. Once that is done, then you could create a formula field in the `object A` with formula `District_stats__c.District_Rev__c`, this field will reflect the value that is in the district_stats__c records which is added as a lookup.